# Why do I get a "member function not present" error when evaluating expressions on the VC++ debugger?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

I've got a static method, `MyClass::myMethod()` on another DLL, `MyDll.dll`. In my code, I call this method, and it compiles and runs fine.

But when I try `MyClass::myMethod()` in the immediate window (or the watch window), I always get:

```
MyClass::myMethod()
CXX0052: Error: member function not present
```

Why is that?

**Update**: I've found out that when I use the [context operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wztycb7f.aspx) it works:

```
{,,MyDLL}MyClass::myMethod()
```

I'm not really sure why it's needed, though, so I'm going to wait a bit to see if someone has a nice explanation.

**Update 2**: I was asked to give more information. Unfortunately, what I described is almost all I have. This is in third-party code. The method, which resides on a different DLL, is declared like this:

```
class MyClass
{
 public:
 // ...
 _declspec(dllimport) static const char *getDirectory(void);
}
```

and it is invoked like this:

```
MyClass::getDirectory ()
```

I haven't got the source. It was compiled on Debug mode under VC++9.

Comment: It seems like the watch window is just not smart enough, and can't locate the source to run this way. Have you tried wrapping this call with a function of your own - char* foo() { return MyClass::getDir(); } ? It might work this way, as the source of MyClass would be resolved at compile time rather than runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure why, but the debugger isn't smart enough to know that class is in another DLL, so you have to explictly tell it by using the [context operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wztycb7f(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
{,,MyDLL}MyClass::myMethod()
```

Comment: Worked for me (after I loaded the PDB for the module). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your static function is defined inline.

My test with this class:

```
class myclass
{
public:
    static int inlinetest() 
    { 
        return 0; 
    }
    static int test();
};

int myclass::test()
{
    return 0;
}
```

gives me this output in my immediate window:

```
myclass::inlinetest()
CXX0052: Error: member function not present
myclass::test()
0
```

Comment: @fretje It's not inline - this class in another, closed source, DLL. I've actually managed to get it to work (see my update), but I don't really know why.