# Evaluate instance methods in Visual Studio 2008 C++ Express

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008

I need to debug some parts of a quite complex application based on Qt (QGis), and I've used VS 2008 C++ Express to build it with debug informations (removing optimization with /Od).
I can inspect simple type variables (like int, string, etc.), but I cannot evaluate instance methods, because it throws errors saying that the method doesn't exist, etc. (CXX0052 errcode).

Do I have to compile in debug mode to have a deeper insight available?
Is the expression evaluator supposed to let me inspect instance methods?
Or, is VS Express debugger more limited then the complete VS?

Answer (score 0):

You can get errors like this if your method is defined inline or if your method is in another assembly.  I have found that if the method is not inline and in the same assembly I can always evaluate like this in the immediate window:

```
?myObject.myFunc()
```

You might find this thread useful: [Why do I get a "member function not present" error when evaluting expressions on the VC++ debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051611/why-do-i-get-a-member-function-not-present-error-when-evaluting-expressions-on)

Comment: Thanks Graeme. Very useful informations.
Where did you find the use of "?". I didn't hit in reading the (spread) Windows documentation

Comment: I didn't get it from any documentation, I just saw a coworker do it once.  There's no better way to learn than to stare over another programmer's shoulder :)