# how can is see the state of the error flag? Can I put error state flag in watch?

Tags: visual-c++

I am learning about C++, thus beginner question.

the iostream cin has error state error flag like goodbit, eofbit, failbit, badbit

can I see how this change by putting them in the watch? if so what do I have to write?
If not how can I see how the error state flags change?

Comment: By "watch", do you mean the debugger's watch, where you can display e.g. the value of a variable?

Answer (score 0):

To display the flags of `cin` in the Watch window while debugging:

Enter in the watch window:

```
std::cin.flags()
```

or

```
std::cin.good()
```

etc.

**But: This probably won't work right away.**

The default project configuration links the C(++) Runtime Library is dynamically (i.e. using a DLL). There seems to be an issue with the debugger/watch that you have to specify the context of a function if it's defined in a DLL, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051611/why-do-i-get-a-member-function-not-present-error-when-evaluting-expressions-on).

A quick workaround is to set up the project to statically link to the C(++) Runtime Library; in VS2010 it's under the project configuration -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library -> set to "Multi-threaded Debug" (instead of "Multi-threaded Debug DLL").